# Shopping Cart Row Count

Tags: codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter for a project.

Here is what my cart look like

No.1|Appple |Qty -2

No.2|Orange |Qty -3

No.3|Orange |Qty -3

Normally if I use "$this->cart->total_items();" . I will get 2+3+3 = 8. 
However , I only want rowcount(see there are three row) . I want to show '3' . Is there any thing like '$this->cart->rowcount()' ?

Comment: [The user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/cart.html) and viewing the library's source would answer your own question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm just guessing here (as I'm not somewhere where I can test this), but you might try:

```
$rows = count($this->cart->contents());
```

I'm assuming that the array that's returned has an array of each item type with a quantity value.