# Issue using count($this->cart->contents()); in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cart

[Old code]: I want to get the count of the cart content on the header section of the view page.
I am using:

```
<?php echo count($this->cart->contents()); ?>
```

[New code update]:Try this

```
<?php echo $rows = count($this->cart->contents()); ?>
```

But the moment I put this on the header of the view page in codeigniter, the whole page goes blank except the header.

I have already tried  `<?php echo count($this->cart->contents()); ?>` but it does not work in my case.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: Because `$this` is not available at a time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shopping Cart Row Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775486/shopping-cart-row-count)

Comment: Inside your cart class make a method returns de count elements of contents, then put in your header view <?=$this->methodReturnCount()?>

Im not sure because, $this->cart->contents()... cart is the current object or what ? if it the current object u musn't do $this->cart should be $this->contents()

Comment: whats the output ? if the page is blank that means there's an error in the header and the page stopped executing , can you take a look at the source code in the browser and give us more details ?

Comment: The header remains as such but it freezes, it has some user information dropdown but it does not work and the body and the footer disappears completely.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue.

Just include cart in your autoload.php file if it's not already included. Just including in your individual controllers won't be helpful.

$autoload['libraries'] = array('session','cart');

Comment: Please improve your answer by posting some code that solved the issue

Comment: Please don't post solution's code inside comments, edit your answer with the code instead.